# Java regex predefined character class?

Tags: java, regex

I have this regex, which attempts to combine the predefined character class **\s** with **,** :

```
String rgx = "[^\s,]"
```

But I get an error saying that \s is an illegal escape character. I can't double backslash \s, because if I do then the character class it will be interpreted as a backslash and a letter 's'. What can I do?

Comment: `I can't double backslash \s, because if I do then the character class it will be interpreted as a backslash and a letter 's'` are you sure about that. Could you show us have you test it?

Comment: `it will be interpreted as a backslash and a letter 's'` are you sure? Composing regexes in java needs doublethink... Umm, I mean double escaping... So a to represent single backslash to be exactly matched, you need `\\\\ `

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to match? The proposed regex seems to say "match any non space and non `,` character". Is it wat you try to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, my assumption about not being able to double backslash \s was wrong. It was indeed the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In java you must double escape the predefined classes.

```
String rgx = "[^\\s,]";
```